# helpsvc.exe get my 100% CPU usage

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

I encounter a problem these day when I turn on my pc or wake it up from stand by I see my cpu usage is on 100%, when I monitor my processor by procexp.exe , it's shows me that helpsvc.exe get my 100% of cpu , I want know what is it? is it normal? what I should do to solve it?

> I have Windows-XP SP3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [known bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/cyrusn/archive/2004/05/31/145044.aspx), Microsoft released a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;839017) for it a little while ago.